# Increase/Decrease a value and display results in a Label inside a TableViewCell Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, button, tableview, uitableview

I have a ViewController with a TableView and a TableViewCell containing multiple sections and rows. 
I have 2 button "plus" and "minus" and a label "totalLabel" in each row.

How can I get the value displayed in the label for each specific row when the user presses the **+** or **-** button?

for now when I run the app and press the + or - buttons only the totalLabel of the section 0/row 0 is working while random values just appear and disappear in the other sections/rows

my tableViewCell code :

```
import UIKit

protocol CommandeCellDelegate: class {
}

class CommandeCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate : CommandeCellDelegate!

@IBOutlet weak var drinksLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var minusButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

}
```

here is my code for cellForRowAt :

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CommandeCellDelegate {

var count : Int = 0

var countValue : String!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommandeCell", for: indexPath) as! CommandeCell

    cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.section
    cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.increaseValue), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.minusButton.tag = indexPath.section
    cell.minusButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.minusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.decreaseValue), for: .touchUpInside)

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let softInfo = softs[indexPath.row]
        cell.drinksLabel?.text = softInfo.drinkName
        cell.totalLabel?.text = // how to display countValue here?

        let HappyHourStatus = partner!.barHHStatus
        if case "0" = HappyHourStatus {
            cell.priceLabel?.text = softInfo.drinkHHPrice
        } else
            if case "1" = HappyHourStatus {
                cell.priceLabel?.text = softInfo.drinkPrice
        }
    }

        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cocktailInfo = cocktails[indexPath.row]
        cell.drinksLabel?.text = cocktailInfo.drinkName
        cell.totalLabel?.text = // how to display countValue here?

        let HappyHourStatus = partner!.barHHStatus
        if case "0" = HappyHourStatus {
            cell.priceLabel?.text = cocktailInfo.drinkHHPrice
        } else
            if case "1" = HappyHourStatus {
                cell.priceLabel?.text = cocktailInfo.drinkPrice
        }
    }
        return cell
}
```

and my funcs to increase or decrease the value :

```
func increaseValue(_ sender: UIButton) -> Int {

    count = 1 + count
    print(count)

    countValue = "\(count)"

    let rowToReload = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: sender.tag)
    let rowsToReload: [Any] = [rowToReload]
    tableView.reloadRows(at: rowsToReload as! [IndexPath], with: .automatic)

    return count
}

func decreaseValue(_ sender: UIButton) -> Int {

    if count == 0 {
        print("Count zero")
    } else {
        count = count - 1
    }

    countValue = "\(count)"

    let rowToReload = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: sender.tag)
    let rowsToReload: [Any] = [rowToReload]
    tableView.reloadRows(at: rowsToReload as! [IndexPath], with: .automatic)

    return count

}
```

I have tried countless solutions but so far none is working - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem is this code

```
cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.section
cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

A tag can only store one value. So you are overriding the section with the row. So it is going to cause all sorts of weirdness. The better solution is to determine what cell you are targeting based on the button itself. Since you know what button was clicked you can convert the location of this button to a point on the table view. And then that point to a a particular index path.

So using your example code you can do something like below:

```
var softsCount: [Int] = []
var cocktailsCount: [Int] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    softsCount = Array(repeating: 0, count: softs.count) // Fill an array with 0
    cocktailsCount = Array(repeating: 0, count: cocktails.count) // Fill an array with 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        ...
        cell.totalLabel?.text = "\(softsCount[indexPath.row])"
        ...
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        ...
        cell.totalLabel?.text = "\(cocktailsCount[indexPath.row])"
        ...
    }
    ...
}

func increaseValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let pointInTable = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable), let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            softsCount[indexPath.row] += 1
            cell.totalLabel?.text = "\(softsCount[indexPath.row])"
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cocktailsCount[indexPath.row] += 1
            cell.totalLabel?.text = "\(cocktailsCount[indexPath.row])"
        }
    }
}
```

No sure why you are returning count. I am sure this is just a partial implementation. But the button should take care of the entire action including updating the label with the new count. You don't normally return values from button presses.

So updated the example to update the label with the current count. Since I am unable to see what your drinks object I made an assumption that the drinks class has a count parameter that starts at 0. This way each individual drink has a count assigned to it.

Comment: Current TextField? I think it might be button?

Comment: Sorry that is what I get when copying and pasting code from a current project. Updated to use the correct variable names.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I changed my increase/decrease value func but now all the rows display the value. How can I get my totalLabel to return the value for only the row where the buttons were tapped ?

Comment: So you need to update your datasource. So that it has the correct values. And then you should probably use your datasource to calculate the new total. Instead of relying on a count variable. I would also only update the labels instead of the entire row. Let me update my code to give you a better idea.

Comment: So updated the example to update the label with the current count. Since I am unable to see what your drinks object I made an assumption that the drinks class has a count parameter that starts at 0. This way each individual drink has a count assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code, my drinks class don't have count parameters, they contain retrieved jsondata with infos such as drinkName and drinkPrice for a specific drink. `var softs = [Soft]() var cocktails = [Cocktail]()` if you could explain how to add count parameters that would be really helpful !

Comment: So there are two basic ways to do this. The best way is to just add the count parameter to the class at print it to 0. The second way is to set up secondary arrays/dictionaries to handle the counts. The second way would probably be easiest based on what I have seen so far. You would add this to wherever you are initializing softs/cocktails. I will add it above to a viewDidLoad for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Ok code has been updated. Again this is not best practice but will accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Can anyone help me? I used same code for increasing and decreasing value of lable but i am having searchController in the same tableview and when i search it increase/decreasing value correctly but when i cancel searchController than it always show wrong label on wrong row. I mean it always display value according to normal tableview not according to my searchController row.